# C Primer Plus chapter 6 exercise 4 check

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Now I'm reading "C Primer Plus" by Stephen Prata and there's an exercise 4 in chapter 6 which has no solution in the book, so I can't check if I did it properly. My code works like it should, but I want to know maybe there are some better or cleaner solutions. Can you, guys, help me? My code is below the description of the exercise.

Here's description:
*Have a program request the user to enter an uppercase letter. Use nested loops to produce a pyramid pattern like this:*

```
    A
   ABA
  ABCBA
 ABCDCBA
ABCDEDCBA
```

*The pattern should extend to the character entered. For example, the preceding pattern would result from an input value of E . Hint: Use an outer loop to handle the rows. Use three inner loops in a row, one to handle the spaces, one for printing letters in ascending order, and one for printing letters in descending order.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch;
    char row;
    char spaces;
    char let;
    char back;

    printf("Please, insert an uppercase letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &ch);

    for(row = 'A'; row <= ch; row++) {
        for(spaces = ch; spaces > row; spaces--)
            printf("%c", ' ');

        for(let = 'A'; let <= row; let++)
            printf("%c", let);    

        for(back = let; back > 'A' + 1; back--)
            printf("%c", back - 2);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, congratulations.

Comment: If the code is working (and produces expected output), it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Be sure to include more information about what kind of advice you're looking for other than "better or cleaner solutions."

Comment: @remyabel thank you for the link and advice.

Comment: Actually, the code doesn't work. Try inputting `D` and/or `F`. It works for `E`, but that was just an example. It should work for any letter.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, I misunderstood the description. "The pattern should extend to the character entered". I thought it should have exact same amount of characters like in the example. My bad.

Comment: In general, the code looks really good. Just a little tweaking and it'll be perfect in no time. Good luck!

Comment: Yup, looks good! The output from `Z` looks cool.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define AtoZ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

int main(void) {
    char ch, *p;
    int row, spaces;
    int r, i;

    printf("Please, insert an uppercase letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if((p = strchr(AtoZ, ch))==NULL){
        printf("invalid input!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    row = p - AtoZ + 1;
    for(r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        spaces = row - r -1;
        for(i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            printf("%c", ' ');

        for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
            printf("%c", AtoZ[i]);

        for(;i >= 0; i--)
            printf("%c", AtoZ[i]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed my code so now it's correct. You use if statement, but in the book it appears later, so your solution is irrelevant. But thanks anyway:)

Comment: `(p = strchr(AtoZ, ch))!=NULL || (exit((printf("invalid input!\n"),-1)),0);`

Answer (score 1):

I think yours are good.  I just change very little bit (and thus a very little bit cleaner):

1. Print a space won't need "%c". Just " ".
2. Carefully design it, so that no +1 and -2 is needed.
3. Naming of the variables: mid: middle of a row, forth: printing forward (i.e. From A to X-1, back: printing backward i.e. From X to A.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(void) {
       char ch;
       char mid;
       char spaces;
       char forth;
       char back;

       printf("Please, insert an uppercase letter: ");
       scanf("%c", &ch);

       for(mid = 'A'; mid <= ch; mid++) {
           for(spaces = ch; spaces > mid; spaces--)
               printf(" ");

           for(forth = 'A'; forth < mid; forth++)
               printf("%c", forth);    

           for(back = mid; back >= 'A'; back--)
               printf("%c", back);
           printf("\n");
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

--- Update ---
Alternatively, the forth and back loop can be replaced by:

```
for (let = 'A'; let < mid; let++)
    printf ("%c", let);
for (   ;  let >= 'A'; let--)
    printf ("%c", let);
```

Yet, you need to define `int let;` instead of `int forth; int back;`

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: Updated an alternative for the forth and back loop.